# Hide softkey board In Fragment when click on Screen Android

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-softkeyboard

I want to hide the soft keyboard shown on the screen when click any where on the screen how can do this.
its working fine when working with activity but not working when working with fragments , how can i manage this

Comment: what have you tried? doesnt your fragment receive the click event? what exactly doesnt work?

Comment: i override the Method Ontouch in fragment activity but if i switch between fragments that causing me  crash not working properly